# Show: $f_n\geqq 0$ with $f_n\nearrow f\text{ a.s.}\implies\int f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\int f\, d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f,f_n\colon (\Omega,\mathfrak{A})\to (\overline{\mathbb{R}},\overline{\mathcal{B}})$ be measurable functions. Show: If $f_n\geq 0$ and $f_n\nearrow f$ a.s. then 
> >     $$
> > \int f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\int f\, d\mu.
> > $$

My idea to prove that is to use two statements we had in recent lectures:

> > **Statement 1** Let $f,f_n$ be non-negative, measurable functions. Then from $0\leq f_n\nearrow f$ it follows $0\leq\int f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\int f\, d\mu$.

and additionally

> > **Statement 2** Let $f,g$ be two measurable functions. If $f=g$ a.s. and $f\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$, then $g\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$ and $\int f\, d\mu=\int g\, d\mu$.

---

*Proof:*

Consider $N:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega: f_n(\omega)\not\to f(\omega)\right\}$. Then by statement 1, because of
$$
0\leq 1_{N^C}f_n\nearrow 1_{N^C}f
$$
it is
$$
\int 1_{N^C}f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\int 1_{N^C}f\, d\mu.~~~~~(*)
$$
Moreover it is 
$$
f_n=1_{N^C}f_n\text{ a.s.},~~~~~~~~~f1_{N^C}=f\text{ a.s.}.
$$

Here is one point I am not totally sure about: Can $f_n1_{N^C}$ and $f1_{N^C}$ now be considered as integrable functions? I mean: The statement 1 says (*) and writes down the integrals... but does this automatically mean that the functions are integrable? I think it only means that they are quasi-integrable! Does statement 2 hold for quasi-integrable functions, too?

If yes, I can use statement 2, getting
$$
\int f_n\, d\mu=\int 1_{N^C}f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\int 1_{N^C}f_n\, d\mu=\int f\, d\mu.
$$

Greetings

Miro

Comment: I don't think that statement 1 implies that the functions are integrable. If I understood correctly, those functions could take values in $ \bar {\mathbb R} $ too. Maybe you can use the fact that $\int 1_{N}f = 0$ and just add it at the end and get your result because $f=f1_{N}+f1_{N^C}$.

Comment: How do you mean that: adding it in the end?

Comment: what a.s. means?

Comment: @Maryam it means almost surely, which is the same as almost everywhere: everywhere outside of some $\mu$-null set.

Comment: @JonathanY. Statement 1 is what I have to show, but only for non-negative measurable functions. So I tried to use that to show it for any functions.

Comment: @mathfemi Adding a $0$ won't affect the result, so the integrals converge to $\int 1_{N^C}f= \int 1_{N^C}f+\int 1_{N}f =\int f$

Comment: @dafinguzman But how does this help?

Comment: @mathfemi Isn't that what you have to prove? As you have already proved (*), it only remains to show that the right hand side is indeed equal to $\int f$

Comment: Ok, but where do I need statement 2 then?

Comment: Maybe you don't.

Comment: This is [Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't really need statement 2. You already proved that $$\int 1_{N^C}f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\int 1_{N^C}f\, d\mu,$$ but since $\int 1_Nf_n\, d\mu$ and $\int 1_Nf\, d\mu$ equal $0$, you can safely say that
$$\int 1_{N^C}f_n\, d\mu  +\int 1_Nf_n\, d\mu \nearrow \int 1_{N^C}f\, d\mu+\int 1_Nf\, d\mu.$$
The left hand side equals $\int f_n\, d\mu$ (by linearity and the fact that $1_N+1_{N^C}=1$), the right hand side equals $\int f\, d\mu$, and the result follows.